# MVC Nested Master Pages and RenderPartial with Ajax form

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm facing an issue with nested masterpages in Asp.net MVC 2.0.

When using a normal master (not nested - below default.master), the login functionality works fine.

Using the nested master, the ajax form post results in a full page render of the default.master inside the UpdateTarget div. Since in this case the referred master is twocolumn.master this makes no sense.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Setup & Code:

default.master:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleTagContent" runat="server" />
        </title>
        <!--script includes --> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="brand">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="/content/site_images/lgo_justProud.gif" width="264" height="62" alt="Just Proud" /></a></div>
                <div id="logMenu" class="noPrint">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="LoginContentArea" runat="server">
                        <div id="login">
                             <%if (SessionHelper.LoggedInUser == null)
                      {
                          Html.RenderPartial("UserNamePasswordLogin", null);

                      }
                      else
                      {
                          Html.RenderPartial("UserLoginStatus", null);                              
                      }; %>
                        </div>
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content_MainZone" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

TwoColumn.master:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content_MainZone" runat="server">
    <div class="bodyTop">
    </div>
    <div class="headerSmall">
        <h1>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content_SubTitle" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="twoColumns">
        <div class="contentLeft">

                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content_MainLeft" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <div class="contentRight">

                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content_MainRight" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

        </div>
        <div class="clearfloats" />


    </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadTagContent" ID="Content2" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadTagContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleTagContent" ID="Content3" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleTagContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</asp:Content>
```

UserNamePasswordLogin.ascx:

```
<div class="notLoggedIn">
<%using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Authentication", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "login" }))
  { %>

  <%=Html.ValidationSummary()%>


<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="username" colspan="2">
            <%--<input name="username" type="text" value="username" size="12" />--%>
            <%=Html.TextBox("username", null, new { size = "12" })%>
            <%=Html.ValidationMessage("username", "*")%>
        </td>
        <td class="password">
            <%--<input name="password" type="text" value="Password" size="12" />--%>
            <%=Html.Password("password", null, new { size = "12" })%>
            <%=Html.ValidationMessage("password", "*")%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%=Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.RawUrl)%>
             <%-- <input type="button" value="Go" />--%>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />               
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input name="rememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="usernameTxt" align="left" width="90">
            <span class="txt">
                <%=GlobalizationProperties.Labels.RememberMe%></span>
        </td>
        <td class="passwordTxt">
            <span class="txt"><a href="#">Forgot your pasword</a></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<%};%>
```

Login Action :

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string username, string password, bool? rememberMe, string returnUrl)
    {            
        LoginDTO dto = new LoginDTO() { Login = username, Password = password, RememberMe = rememberMe };
        // Basic parameter validation
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
            ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("username", GlobalizationProperties.ErrorMessages.LoginRequired);
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("password", GlobalizationProperties.ErrorMessages.PasswordRequired);
        }


        if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            bool loginSuccess = LoginHelper.PerformLogin(dto);

            if (loginSuccess)
            {
                return JavaScript(string.Format("document.location.replace('{0}');", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(returnUrl)));;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("username", GlobalizationProperties.ErrorMessages.LoginPassNotFound);
            }
        }

        ViewData["LoginForm"] = "LoginForm";

        return PartialView("UserNamePasswordLogin");

    }
```

Regards,
Bart

Comment: Is it an AJAX Master page or a regular master page?

Comment: Hi Nick,

Regular master page : Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage"

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using JQuery in place of regular .net ajax